# Isometry between arbitrary $n$-dimensional Euclidean vector space $W$ and the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry

The standard map between $W$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is to send every basis of $W$ bijectively to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is a linear isomorphism between those two vector spaces. I think that the same map also preserves the positive definite inner product structure, i.e., the same map is an isometry. But, I could not the same. Anyone has some idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What does that mean by "I could not the same"?

Comment: Mapping an arbitrary basis of $W$ to an arbitrary basis of $\mathbb R^n$ will almost certainly not give you an isometry (for given inner products on $W$ and $\mathbb R^n$).

Comment: Already the first sentence is ill-formed. What one can say instead is that every finite-dimensional real vector space $W$ is linearly isomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^n$ and that such a linear isomorphism sends bases to bases.

Comment: Robert Israel, can you provide an example where what you are saying is true?

Comment: @BigyanSuryabanshee - $W = \Bbb R$ with basis $\{2\}$ mapped to $\{1\}$ is a quick counter-example. More generally, for an arbitrary $n$-dimensional inner product space $W$, choose any basis that is not orthonormal and map it to the canonical basis of $\Bbb R^n$. The result will not be an isometry. If you map orthonormal bases to orthonormal bases, then you get an isometry, but most bases are not orthonormal.